# I want to Find $3^{2x} + 7^{\frac{1}{x}}$ when $7^{x+1} = 21^{x}$

Tags: exponentiation

I figured that 
\begin{align*}7^{x+1} &= 21^{x}\\
7^{x+1} &= 3^{x} \times 7^{x} \\
7 &= 3^{x}
\end{align*}
 but I can't go further at the moment.

Comment: $3^{2x}=49$ and $7^{\frac 1x}=3$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Square both sides to reveal that

$$3^{2x}=49$$

$x$ root both sides to reveal that

$$7^{1/x}=3$$

Thus,

$$3^{2x}+7^{1/x}=52$$

Answer (score 2):

You have : $7^{\frac{1}{x}} = 3$ and $3^{2x} = 7^2$. Thus $7^{\frac{1}{x}} + 3^{2x} = 52$

Answer (score -1):

Take the logarithm on both sides.

Comment: I do not think this actually helps.  Did you try working it out this way?

Comment: Logarithms actually do work, but it's a tedious and bruteforce method.

Comment: This can also help, you find that $x = \frac{\log(7)}{\log(3)} $ .

Comment: I don't know if it is so tedious $x = \frac {\log 7}{\log 3} = \log_3 7, \frac1x = \log_7 3 \implies 3^{2\log_3 7} + 7^{\log_7 3} = 7^2 + 3$

Comment: @DougM Though definitely not recommended.

Comment: This would be a worthy answer if @DougM's comment were to be incorporated into the body of the answer.